# Bootstrap in Bower Components - 404 (Not Found)

Tags: node.js, twitter-bootstrap, express

I've Googled around and searched Stack Overflow but I can't find an answer that has helped me unfortunately.

I have a small Node project with the following layout:

```
├── app
│   ├── config
│   │   ├── env
│   │   │   ├── development.js
│   │   │   └── production.js
│   │   ├── express.js
│   │   └── index.js
│   ├── controllers
│   │   ├── home.js
│   │   ├── index.js
│   │   ├── metric.js
│   │   ├── metricList.js
│   │   └── metrics
│   │       ├── file2.js
│   │       ├── file3
│   │       ├── file4.js
│   │       ├── file5.js
│   │       ├── file6
│   │       ├── index.js
│   │       └── points.js
│   ├── data
│   │   └── premierLeague
│   │       └── 2015-16.json
│   ├── public
│   │   └── main.css
│   │   └── bower_components
│   ├── routes.js
│   ├── server.js
│   └── views
│       ├── home.handlebars
│       ├── layouts
│       │   └── main.handlebars
│       ├── metric.handlebars
│       └── metricList.handlebars
├── bower.json
├── jsonScript.js
├── npm-debug.log
├── package.json
└── server.js
```

Bootstrap is located in the bower_components folder under public.

In my app/views/layouts/main.handlebars file I require the bootstrap CSS file using the following script tag:

```
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

In my app/config/express.js file (which does a lot of the work of getting the app going), I have this line:

```
  app.use(express.static('./public'));
```

Unfortunately I always see this error in the Chrome console when I host up my app:

```
http://localhost:8080/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

I'd be really grateful if someone could advise me how to either host my bower_components properly using Express or link to it successfully from my main layout. This is driving me mad, I've tried countless combinations and it never seems to work! Many thanks

Comment: I think that you're trying to serve a folder *app/config/public* which doesn't exist. Try this `app.use(express.static('../public'));` notice`..` that should give you path to *app/public*

Answer (score 0):

Try to get the right path:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '../public'));
```

The __dirname get the local directory.

And:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```